# Moving spring 3.1.0 war application to Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How to migrate old 3.1.0 application to Spring boot. Is there any tutorial provided for it? Also is their any tracability matrix for Spring and spring boot version? I am currently trying to use spring boot version 1.2.8.RELEASE. But its not working, giving exception

```
    2016-04-08 17:24:46.125  INFO 18813 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: 
        2016-04-08 17:24:46.130 ERROR 18813 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer.initialize(AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer.java:72)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:570)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:970)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:959)
            at com.citruspay.um.boot.CitrusUMApplication.main(CitrusUMApplication.java:16)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT: Current pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.citruspay</groupId>
            <artifactId>citrus-um</artifactId>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>citrus-um</name>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

            <properties>
                <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
                <org.springframework.security-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
                <org.springframework.orm-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.orm-version>
                <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
                <org.springframework.mobile-version>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.mobile-version>
                <hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate-version>
                <hibernate-validator-version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
                <org.slf4j-version>1.6.0</org.slf4j-version>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
                <tiles-version>3.0.5</tiles-version>
                <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- Newrelic -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>newrel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>newrelic</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Spring Security -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Spring -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.orm-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- SpringAOP + AspectJ -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Hibernate -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
                            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- mysql -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Tiles 2 -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${tiles-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                    <version>${tiles-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Logging -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.15</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Servlet -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                    <version>10.0-b28</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Test -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.11</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.6</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.6</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.23</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-hibernate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.5</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Jedis/Redis client() -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- end jedis -->
                <!-- opencsv -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Git Commit Plugin -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.mobile-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- subsacription -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>14.0.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Jersey -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>1.17.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <version>1.17.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.17.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>1.17.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                    <version>1.17.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- end subscription -->

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.citruscube.utility</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cube-utility</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.3</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.2</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.4</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <files>
                                            <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                                        </files>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.9</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>revision</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <configuration>
                                <prefix>git</prefix>
                                <dateFormat>dd.MM.yyyy '@' HH:mm:ss z</dateFormat>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../.git</dotGitDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>generate-buildnumber</id>
                                    <phase>validate</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>create</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <format>{0,number}</format>
                                        <items>
                                            <item>buildNumber</item>
                                        </items>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>generate-timestamp</id>
                                    <phase>validate</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>create</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</format>
                                        <items>
                                            <item>timestamp</item>
                                        </items>
                                        <buildNumberPropertyName>buildDateTime</buildNumberPropertyName>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <tasks>
                                            <!-- versioning -->
                                            <echo message="[build version]" />
                                            <delete
                                                file="${project.build.directory}/generated-webResources/WEB-INF/views/error/version.jspx" />
                                            <copy
                                                todir="${project.build.directory}/generated-webResources/WEB-INF/views/error">
                                                <fileset dir="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/version">
                                                    <include name="version.jspx" />
                                                </fileset>
                                                <filterset>
                                                    <filter token="VERSION" value="${buildVersion}" />
                                                    <filter token="BUILDNO" value="${buildNumber}" />
                                                    <filter token="BUILTON" value="${buildDateTime}" />
                                                    <filter token="REVISION" value="${git.commit.id}" />
                                                    <filter token="BRANCH" value="${git.branch}" />
                                                </filterset>
                                            </copy>

                                            <echo message=" ============================================" />
                                            <echo message=" version is ${buildNumber}" />
                                            <echo message=" version is  ${git.commit.id}" />
                                            <echo message=" version is  ${git.commit.time}" />
                                            <echo message=" branch is  ${git.branch}" />
                                            <echo message=" ============================================" />
                                        </tasks>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <!-- assamble static content -->
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <server>tomcat7</server>
                                <port>8080</port>
                                <fork>true</fork>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <!-- <plugin> -->
                        <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> -->
                        <!-- <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
                        <!-- <version>2.3</version> -->
                        <!-- </plugin> -->
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-pdfreport-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3</version>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </project>
```

Comment: I have written about my experience migrating to spring boot (but I was using Spring 4) in my blog: http://flnjworkingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/08/migrating-spring-rest-service.html, http://flnjworkingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/08/migrating-spring-rest-service_18.html,http://flnjworkingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/09/migrating-spring-rest-service.html

Answer (score -1):

We have recently moved an application from Spring 3.x to Spring boot.Few points to take care:

1. Do you have an external war file, then keep tomcat dependencies scope as
   provided .
2. Are you annotating Spring boot main class with all
   required dependencies , use @SpringBootApplication for ease.
3. You might would have xml configuration , rather than creating beans for
   all , try using @Import.

Comment: We are planning to deploy .jar file. I have added pom.xml in post. Please let me know which boot version have u used for Spring 3.x?

Comment: Version is 1.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: Kumar Pallav: Can you please share me your pom.xml? It will be helpful if you share it for my reference.